# windows Runas always returns "The System cannot find the file specified"

Tags: winapi, createprocess, runas

Windows runas.exe application does not work when I use the same syntax shown in runas /?. For example one of the usages shown is, `runas /trustlevel<TrustLevel> program`, however, when I use `runas /trustlevel<0x20000> calc` I get "The system cannot find the file specified." What file is it talking about?

I noticed another person asked similar question but they were trying to use console program written using Delphi: [Got "The system cannot find the file specified" when I run NETSH from CreateProcess but it works ok on Command Prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166840/got-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-when-i-run-netsh-from-createproc)
but I am using DOS command in Windows so I don't understand why the same command would run fine if I type in command prompt or Start Menu->Run or Taskmanager->File->Run but won't work when I use runas.

Comment: It's completely unclear what you want, or even what you are talking about.

Comment: Please post commands as code here in your question and not as linked images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<` and `>` is the input and output redirection operators in cmd.exe.  `/trustlevel<0x20000>` is asking cmd.exe to read from a file called 0x20000.

The correct syntax is `runas /trustlevel:0x20000 calc`.

The `<something>` syntax in help output means the parameter is required. `[something]` is optional.

/trustlevel does not change the UAC integrity level so it is not a good way to reduce your rights although it will add a deny-only SID for the administrators group so it is probably implemented with the [Safer API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms722422(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: This doesn't seem to bear any relation to what can be seen above. You shouldn't answer questions of this form until they are fixed.

Comment: @VanenDallas You should have included the problematic command line in your question text, not as a screenshot. The question is probably also a better fit for SuperUser.

Comment: @Anders I understand and I will do that next time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @VanenDallas You could edit your question...

Comment: @Anders revised, thank you